# WKHTMLTOPDF configuration in a .NET 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using a wkhtmltopdf plugin in my .NET 5 MVC project and can't seem to find where to input the configuration.

In the docu it reads that I need to put the params into a command line, however I do not have the program installed and simply just use it in my project via dependency injection.

Here is the Solution Explorer in VS:
[Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA5ut.png)

I use the plugin this way:
[Services config in Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4baC.png)

Inserting the commands into the cmd line in VS does nothing.
Aside from this, the plugin works like a charm!

Thank you for any hints. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you just need to do for example:

```
 ConvertOptions option = new();
 option.PageMargins.Bottom = 0;
 option.PageMargins.Top = 0;
 option.PageMargins.Left = 0;
 option.PageMargins.Right = 0;
 _generatePdf.SetConvertOptions(option);
```

To set the options.